# EF 6, mapping single entity to many tables

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6

We have a unique database structure and would like to use the Entity Frame.
Currently we have a large number of tables that contain the same schema.  The table name has a reference to the primary key in another table.  Take for instance

- Table: Customer
      Primary Key: CustomerId
- Table: User_[CustomerId]

For example the Table Customer has the Primary Key of CustomerId and say has data

CustomerId

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5

The are multiple User tables (1000's of them) in the database.  The table name would be

- User_00001
- User_00002
- User_00003
- User_00004
- User_00005

each of the user tables have the same columns.

This is something that we cannot change.

We would prefer not to import to import the thousand plus tables into the designer.

Is there a way in the Entity Framework that we could map a single entity to a specific table either in the linq call or in an individual context reference?

For instance something like this?

```
 var myUser = db.User(1020).FirstOrDefault(i=>i.UserId == 134);

 or

 db.UserID = 1020;
```

What would the best practice using an ORM be for this?

Comment: Not sure I understand your schema.  Could you layout an example of the 2 tables you mentioned in a better format with a few example rows?  Or even better build a simple one on http://sqlfiddle.com/.

Comment: Added more detail in the description.